# robot_state_publisher fixed frames 0.5s ahead

Tags: robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

The **robot_state_publisher** has 2 different mechanisms for publishing **moving** and **fixed** frames. Moving frames are published on **joint_states** callback.

Does anyone know why **robot_state_publisher** publishes the fixed frames using a timer independent from the **joint_states** subscriber and ahead of 0.5 seconds?

Could not find any valid reason whether from the internet or the code...

Thanks ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189837/robot_state_publisher-fixed-frames-0.5s-ahead/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note: This is a conjecture on my part.

1. When you use TF, usually you query a transform for your data's time. Often this is current data, e.g. from now. If you query the transform for current data it is likely to fail, as the TF data has not arrived, yet. (It will under the hood in a short time, though)
2. Usually this makes some `waitForTransform` constructs necessary, even for fixed transforms, which do not change (TF didn't know this difference at first)
3. Fixed frames are fixed. Therefore they do not change. Hence it is correct to assign any time (e.g. +0.5s) to them.
4. When querying transform data for fixed frames for current data, the TF listener already has data from now + 0.5s and before (because it was send with time stamps 0.5s in the future). Therefore it can interpolate between the transforms and immediately give an answer without waiting.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-08-13**:
Wow, if it is that it is super fiddly! As you would never be in a position to really tell which sample you interpolate from... Keep in mind that fixed frames are fixed with respect to their parent, not with respect to the world, hence if their parent move over time (wrt the world), they also do.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-13**:
This is not a problem. Only the fixed transform would be send predated this way.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-08-13**:
In this case, the following will happen: 1. moving frames are sent at t1, 2. fixed frames are sent at t2 + 0.5 (computed by composing with moving frames at t1), 3. moving frames are sent at t3 < t2 + 0.5, 4. now frames are read. Then when the reading is performed, the fixed position wrt to

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-08-13**:
the world are computed out of the composition of parent moving frames at t1. Hence they are wrong.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-13**:
I don't understand what you are doing there, but this doesn't seem correct. Can you give a concrete example, e.g. with /odom -> /base_link -> /laser, where you think something goes wrong?

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-08-13**:
Ok I update the question in a few minutes

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-08-13**:
While writing an edit for further explanations I realized that you are actually right: at step 4 the computation of the position of the fixed frames wrt to the world uses moving frames at t2 and not t1 and interpolates the fixed frames (which does not do anything as they are constant).

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-08-13**:
Thanks for provoking these thoughts ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just an idea, answer not based on knowledge: sensor_msgs/JointState contains header with stamp, might be that the tf of the moving frames uses the time stamp from the sensor_msgs/JointState it receives in the callback..??

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-08-13**:
I believe you are right about the moving frames inheriting their time stamp from sensor_msgs/JointState. But how does that help?